# How do I remove the shadows for all Buttons in MUI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I want to remove the shadows for all contained buttons in my custom MUI theme but I don't know how to go about it so far. How do I do so? I have tried setting the boxShadow property for each individual Button to Zero but that's not working.

Answer (score 9):

You could use a `Button` prop named [`disableElevation`](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/button/) (which is `false` by default)

You could use it per component or set globally in theme setting

In a single component

```
<Button variant="contained" disableElevation={true}>
  a button
</Button>
```

Globally via theme setting

```
const theme = createTheme({
  components: {
    MuiButton: {
      defaultProps: {
        disableElevation: true
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Codesandbox demo

[image: Edit gracious-hermann-0lvvlj]